# Subsequence of colorings converges to coloring

Tags: real-analysis

Say you have a finite number of colors $r$. For each positive integer $N$, there exists a function $\phi_N: [N] \rightarrow [r]$, which specifies a coloring of the integers in $[N]$. Is it true that there exists an infinite subsequence of the $\phi_N$'s such that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\phi_N(k)$, as $N$ increases along this infinite subsequence converges to some color.

I think this has something to do with the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem but I am having trouble fitting it exactly into that context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Define $N_{0,m}=m$. For each $k\geq 1$ pick a subsequence $(N_{k,m})_{m\geq 1}$ of the sequence $(N_{k-1,m})_{m\geq 1}$ such that $\phi_{N_{k,m}}(k)$ exists and converges as $m\to \infty$. Then for each $k$ the diagonal sequence  $\phi_{N_{m,m}}(k)$ converges as $m\to\infty$, as required.

For the connection to Bolzano-Weierstrass, fix a real sequence $x_1,x_2,\dots\in[0,1)$ and define $\phi_N(i)$ to be the $i$'th decimal digit of $x_N$ with some fixed choice of decimal representation. Then you get a subsequence on which each decimal digit converges.